# Json View doesn't restrict the fields in the response

Tags: java, spring, jackson, json-view

I need to send only 1 field annotated with @JsonView(in my case : eNumber) in my response. Also, this has to be only when the call is from Controller1 which also has a JsonView annotation.
But, eNumber field value is sent also when the call is from Controller2 which is not annotated with @JsonView. What am I missing here ?

Below is my code:

DTO:

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonView(Views.InternalRequest.class)
    public String getEnumber() {        
      
      return eNumber;
    }
    
    .... other fields
}
```

Controller classes :

```
@RequestMapping("/api/ctr")
public class Controller1 {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{serviceId}/eva", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @JsonView(Views.InternalRequest.class)
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> findAllEva() {
    
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MyClass());
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/api/abcd")
public class Controller2 {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{serviceId}/evss", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> findAllEvs() {
    
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MyClass());
    }
}
```

View:

```
public class Views {
    public static class InternalRequest {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do the following:

1. Define two views; one for internal one for public.
2. Annotate the fields not the getters (I believe, not 100% sure about this step).
3. Annotate the Controller2 method with "@JsonView(Views.Public.class)"

Here is a [Baeldung article describing JsonViews](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Comment: DwB: It didn't work. Should I create some Custom serializer or something to make this JsonView work ?

Comment: I wrote some test code and revised my answer.